# google syntax in exposed filter for text field

Tags: 7, views

Is there a way to use google syntax in views exposed filters for texts fields (e.g. title)?

examples:

dog -cat (search for titles with "dog" that have not "cat")

"black dog" (search for titles containing "black dog", and not only "black" or "dog")

thank you